# Accessing local git progress from another machine without committing

Tags: git

I have two workstations I use; one at home, one at the office. To date, when I've wanted to continue working on a project at one location from the other, I've just committed my changes.

But this results in a foolishly busy commit log, and more often than not commits that don't reflect finished or presumed-stable code. Often what I really want is just to continue whatever feature I'm working on without having to commit something as yet unfinished.

One thought that comes to mind is that I'm probably branching too little; if I really had a branch for every individual feature, then at least the merge would always reflect code that is ready.

But *is* there a way to "pull" from a local clone without committing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git is not designed for code syncing. Thus it does not provide such a feature. You should definitely focus on how you can minimize turning the change log into  garbage.

I guess branches is the correct way to go. If you use feature branch strategy, you will automatically see that your commits will be grouped to branches by feature. This will help keeping your change history more tidy.

In fact this is already the extreme programming strategy **commit often**. When you group commits to meaningful branches you are encouraged to commit as much as possible with small, even tiny, chunks of changes. However a commit with log *"End of day"* is still a bit ugly if you ask me.

If you do not want to go into much trouble then you can also create a dedicated branch for code syncing. You can make merges with `--squash` flag, so that your meaningless *"End of day"* commits and meaningful commits are combined into a single commit while merging into master (or any other high quality) branch neatly.